# How to use a web service as a datasource in Spotfire

Tags: sql-server, web-services, ironpython, spotfire

There is a use case in which we would like to add columns from the data of a webservice to our original sql data table.

If anybody has done that then pls do comment.

Comment: Buddy, you have come to the wrong place. Please read [ask].

Comment: Sure I'll give a read..thanks Shadowfax :)

Answer (score 2):

Shadowfax is correct that you should review the How to Ask guide.

that said, Spotfire offers this feature in two ways:

1. use IronPython scripting attached to an action control to retrieve the data. this is a very rigid solution that offers no caching, and the data must be retrieved and placed in memory each time the document is opened. I'll leave you to the search feature here on SO; I've posted a sample document somewhere.
2. the ideal solution is to use a separate product called Spotfire Advanced Data Services. this data federation layer can mashup data and perform advanced, custom caching based on your needs. the data is then exposed as an information link in Spotfire Server. you'll need to talk to your TIBCO sales rep about this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Web Server to consume the Web Service and write it to your DB.

But here is the hard way:

Step 1: Use IronPython Script to retrieve WS Data, and form a Data Table or Document Property (https://www.tibco.com/blog/2014/03/03/streaming-xml-and-json-data-from-the-web-directly-into-spotfire-clients-using-script-controls/)

Step 2: Write a Stored Procedure in your DB and use IronPython to call the procedure (using a button, so this will be a manual step) and pass the Data Table or Document Property as parameter. (Here is an ironpython alternative: http://spotfired.blogspot.com/2014/04/write-back-to-database-from-spotfire.html)